# How to get the file format in C++/Qt

Tags: c++, qt, file

I need to write a program that allows me to read the names of every file in a directory, and also the type of a file. While I can get the filenames, I am unable to get how I am supposed to find the type. The only thing I can think of is to use its metadata, but I'm not even sure how to begin with that. 
I'm trying for an OS independent solution, but I'll be happy if it works only on Windows or Linux only as well.

**Note**: Please do NOT give solutions that involve searching for a dot, and anything in between. These days, almost no file had a `.pdf` or something attached to it. When you read the filename, all you get is `sample`, and not `sample.txt`.

Also, if it is not compatible with Qt, I'd appreciate if you could mention this in your answer so I can look take appropriate actions (I'm working on Qt because of GUI).

Comment: "These days, almost no file had a .pdf or something attached to it." What? Maybe if you use a *nix OS, but not on Windows, as Windows relies on the extension to be able to know the type of the file. And because the majority of users use Windows, I would say that you can't generalize it like that.

Comment: If you want to find the file type, say so. Don't use the word "extension", it has nothing to do with the file type.

Comment: If you are on windows, extensions are mandatory for windows to associate files with programs. Just because the file explorer hides them from *you*, doesn't mean they aren't there.

Comment: @Rakete1111 The **vast** majority of users use Android OS.

Comment: @n.m. ... as a desktop/laptop OS. You know what I mean :P

Comment: Utilize the [QFileInfo](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html) class or use Boost.

Comment: File extensions is mandatory on all OS. Even Linux has to rely on the file extension if there is no unique header in the file. `QFileInfo` is super easy for this and also the top result on Google using "file extension qt"...

Comment: It is my fault for not using a 'file extension qt' as a search query, was too focused on the 'c++ file extension' query :(

Comment: @Rakete1111 I meant that it is not shown when using commands to retrieve file names. My method on ubuntu was using ls command and that caused me to have 'file' instead of 'mp4' when I renamed em. This was kinda irritating.

Answer (score 10):

### File Extension

As @CMLDMR pointed out, [`QFileInfo::suffix()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#suffix) and [`QFileInfo::completeSuffix()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#completeSuffix) methods will return the file **extension**. However, file extension may be omitted, invalid, unknown, etc.

So, according to your actual question, you want to know the file format, not its extension as stated in the [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41437695/1).

### File Format

Qt 5 has a class [`QMimeDatabase`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedatabase.html). It allows you to discover the file MIME type by its contents. Let's say we have an `mpeg` music file with no extension:

```
QMimeDatabase db;
QMimeType mime = db.mimeTypeForFile("C:/music", QMimeDatabase::MatchContent);
qDebug() << mime.name();            // Name of the MIME type ("audio/mpeg").
qDebug() << mime.suffixes();        // Known suffixes for this MIME type ("mp3", "mpga").
qDebug() << mime.preferredSuffix(); // Preferred suffix for this MIME type ("mp3").
```

### File Extension + File Format

If you still want to give priority to the file extension and parse the file contents only if the suffix is **not** present, omit the `QMimeDatabase::MatchContent` argument – the default `QMimeDatabase::MatchDefault` will be used. See [`QMimeDatabase::MatchMode`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedatabase.html#MatchMode-enum) for more informtaion.

---

Note that Qt uses different MIME databases for different operating systems, so the results may vary.

Answer (score 9):

```
QFileInfo fi("/tmp/archive.tar.gz");
QString ext = fi.suffix();  // ext = "gz"
```

suffix function is give you a file extension.

OR

```
QFileInfo fi("/tmp/archive.tar.gz");
QString ext = fi.completeSuffix();  // ext = "tar.gz"
```

you can use each of other which one is correct for you.
This code independent but Qt.

For Details [LINK](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html#suffix)

Comment: Yep..this is what I'm looking for, but what if my file is something like /C/helloworld. Will this give me a txt as a QString?

Comment: Your file should have an extension in the first place. You may not see it (some Linux file explorers hide them), but you should have one, due to the exact problem you're facing. The OS cannot guess what a file is without its extension. Looking at the documentation, it won't return anything, since Qt just looks for what's after the last dot.